# Regex Match between special character

Tags: regex

I have a string similar to this:

```
++ name1
description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf \n

++ name2
description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf \n

++ name3 description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf
```

I want to extract it into groups like:

```
group1:
name1
description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf

group2:
name2
description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf

group3:
name3
description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf
```

How to do this with regex?

Comment: whats the difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: [And you've tried...what, exactly?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @christianScheider the first is one string I want to split it into groups , I know (++) is the splitter

Comment: @JackManey I have tried this (?<=\+\+).*[\S\s]*(?=\+\+) but it return all the groups as one string except from the last one

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @AndyLester read the previous comment and u will see what i have tried

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thats what u like?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    String text = "++ name1\n" +
            "description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf \\n\n" +
            "++ name2\n" +
            "description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf \\n\n" +
            "++ name3 description:asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf\n" +
            "++ name4 :asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf\n" +
            "++ name5 asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf\n";
    System.out.println(text);


    System.out.println("\n\n\nResult:");
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\+\\+ (.*?)\\s+(?:description)?:?([\\p{Alpha}]+)\\s*").matcher(text);
    //                                 ^           ^    `- the description "could" be there.              
    //                                 |            `- read the whitespaces and linebreaks 
    //                                 \ the two ++ and the whitespace
    //                                       

     while(matcher.find())
     {
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " - " + matcher.group(2));
     }
}
```

It will print:

```
Result:
name1 - asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf
name2 - asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf
name3 - asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf
name4 - asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf
name5 - asdfmkdfkmfkskfsaf
```

Comment: WoW it was very fast thanks Christian, but I have one edit "description" is not always part of the string. Only (++) is expected to work as a splitter. I removed "description" from the pattern u provided but it is not getting the whole string, can u help?

Comment: Is this what you mean? The absent of "description:"

Comment: yes, All I know is that there will groups of characters separated by a "++". Any group may contain any character, new line or white spaces

Comment: Is your question now solved?